# Jsoup, connection.excute(), connection.get() is null

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm developing an android app by crawling HTML from an Web site but I got NullPointerException when I'm using connection.get() to get Document.
So I tested like this.

```
try {
    conn = Jsoup.connect(url);
    document = conn.get();
    res = conn.execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (conn != null) {
    textView.append("conn is not null\n");
} else {
    textView.append("conn is null\n");
}

if (document != null) {
    textView.append("document not is null\n");
} else {
    textView.append("document is null\n");
}

if (res != null) {
    textView.append("res is not null.\n");
} else {
    textView.append("res is null\n");
}
```

and the result is

```
conn is not null.
document is null.
res is null.
```

I tried this on http://google.com and the result is

```
conn is not null.
document is not null.
res is not null.
```

and I can get Document, of course.

Why do I get null from connection.excute(), connection.get()?

Comment: Did you check your URL in the browser?

Comment: are try to execute on mainThread??

Comment: @BhalchandraSW    yes I did.

Comment: @Ameer Hamza  yes with this code StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: ok i got it let me post ANS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all looking at the documentation, you don't need to call either execute and get: the connection.get() method

> Execute the request as a GET, and parse the result.

The reason why you don't get any response from your url it's because you try to run on main thread

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I already checked the log and there is nothing. very strange.

Comment: @BaekTheFool use:
Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
Within the catch statement

Comment: Thank you! I thought e.printStackTrace() would show error on the log. Anyway, I got java.io.EOFException and I have a clue now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run inside the background task eg asynctask perfect for this

```
  private class UrlGraber extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


            private String[] urls;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
              try {
                       conn = Jsoup.connect(url);
                       document = conn.get();

                   } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


            }
        }
```

And from your onCreat() call `new urlGraber.excute()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but I got still java.io.EOFException.